# Variable-size parameters to function

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to send an arbitrarily sized argument to a C function.

Right now I'm doing: (A contrived example)

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  float b;
} myStruct;

void foo(int, char)
void bar(int, myStruct)

void* arg;
size_t size = flag ? sizeof(char) : sizeof(myStruct);
void (*fn)(int, ...) = flag ? &foo : &bar;
char data[size];
memcpy(data, arg, size);
fn(42, data);
```

Anyone know of an easier way to do this?

**UPDATE**

What I'm actually trying to do is swizzle an Objective-C property (Similar to the way KVO works). I want to use imp_implementationWithBlock() to create the dynamic implementation, but then I need a way to call the original implementation. originalIMP(_self, _cmd) is all well and good except that the argument at the end can be of variable size (i.e. CGRect, arbitrary struct, etc.). I want do originalImp(_self, _cmd, {struct of size n}).

Comment: Uh, pass a `char*`? (or `void*` as `memcpy` itself takes) See also `union`

Comment: Then make the argument a collection object and "send" it that.

Comment: The way you are doing is is very dangerous. your compiler should have warned you that the prototypes of the function pointer that you assign  are not correct. This gives you undefined behavior. Declare your functions also with variable argument list (`...`).

Comment: this will not work, because when you pass data (an array) to a "..." function (or any function), it will only pass the pointer (not the memory in the array) over the stack, so it will pass parameters equivlanent of fn(int, char*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was having a union of the various data types that the function will accept... then selecting the property type using a switch statement on the size of the argument.